# How to embed a twitter timeline without retweets?

Tags: html, search, twitter, embed

I'm embedding a twitter timeline into my website. However my retweets are being displayed there and I don't want them to.

Is there any easy way to turn them off? I can't seem to find any

My search query is `from:myaccount`. I also tried `from:myaccount -RT`, with no luck. I can hide retweets with a search widget but **tweets older than a week are not shown** which is unacceptable in my case.

Hiding the tweets via some CSS magic would also be OK. I managed to find out that manually inserting

```
div.timeline-Tweet--isRetweet {
  display: none !important;
}
```

in the CSS for the embedded HTML does the trick, but I can't manage to do it programatically.

Comment: Share your code which injects style, maybe there is some obvious bug. Hacky approach with injecting the style worked for me with this little abomination:
`document.querySelector('#twitter-widget-0').contentDocument.querySelectorAll('div.timeline-Tweet--isRetweet').forEach(node => node.style = 'display: none;');`

assuming that timeline iframe has id `#twitter-widget-0`. It is possible to get into guts of the iframe cause timeline iframes are considered as from same domain. 2nd thing is that i don't know whether Twitter widgets license allow for such manipulations.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that! I did not really have any code, as I have no clue about JS. I'm trying yours now and it's not working, even if the id is the same as yours. How should I insert this? I used `<script> yourcode </script>`

Comment: Also, if you post that as a working answer I would definitely accept it.

Comment: i just hit F12 on some random page with Twitter timeline to get myself to browser console and written this... i will do it today as full example... as it requires probably a little bootstrapping to work... like waiting for load event saying that timeline has loaded, etc...

Comment: @gaa @Guido You cannot programmatically change/modify/compromise iframe content, Please don't forget the `cross-domain` policy

Comment: @Medet Tleukabiluly not quite... iframe used by Twitter timeline widget has no src thus browsers consider it as same origin iframe and allow to manipulate and interact with its contents from parent context... nevertheless it hacky as heck

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly can you say more about the cross-domain policy?

Comment: @Guido http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060958/edit-the-css-of-a-cross-domain-iframe-that-is-inside-an-internal-iframe read this

Comment: @Guido altho you already have accepted answer, you must have some considerations: 1. It's not legal way described in terms of use 2. css may change in the future without any error (css doesn't have errors) which may result in future maintenance

Comment: I'm not a lawyer but @Medet may be right about the thing whether it is ok to manipulate iframe contents of the widget. Look at [Developer Agreement & Policy](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/terms/agreement-and-policy) to be precise _II. Restrictions on Use of Licensed Materials.A.2_... I would simply drop an email to Twitter whether they are fine with such thing and would also put there a bit of justification why to go with such approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adaptation from my comments

To go with hacky style injection, simply put following code in script tag. This puts `https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js` script tag to your page so you no longer need it as separate script tag.

```
// widgets script loading taken from Twitter
window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        t = window.twttr || {};
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

    t._e = [];
    t.ready = function (f) {
        t._e.push(f);
    };

    return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    twttr.events.bind("rendered", function (event) {
        var widgetFrame = event.target;
        var retweets = widgetFrame.contentDocument.querySelectorAll('div.timeline-Tweet--isRetweet');
        retweets.forEach(function (node) {
            if (node.parentNode) { // (in)sanity check
                node.parentNode.style = 'display: none;' // hide entire parent li tag
            }
        })
    });
});
```

**Remark about it**

We take parent node as every `div.timeline-Tweet--isRetweet` sits in `li` tag which gives you border, so you end up with some strange double border left after hidden retweets. I think that there is no way to reach parent through CSS selectors so we have to do this with a code.

**Another remark**

Following hack strongly relies on way how contents of the timelines are structured and those may change without the notice from Twitter so you risk here that one day you will wake up with you pants down and retweets back in your timeline ;)

---

**Update**

ok here is v2 which listen for updates on `ol`... but after writing it I start to understand dr Frankenstein feelings ;)

```
window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        t = window.twttr || {};
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

    t._e = [];
    t.ready = function (f) {
        t._e.push(f);
    };

    return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    twttr.events.bind("rendered", function (event) {
        var frameDoc = event.target.contentDocument;

        // initially hide retweets
        var hideRetweets = function () {
            var retweets = frameDoc.querySelectorAll('div.timeline-Tweet--isRetweet');
            retweets.forEach(function (node) {
                if (node.parentNode && node.parentNode.style !== 'display: none;') { // (in)sanity check
                    node.parentNode.style = 'display: none;' // hide entire parent li tag
                }
            });
        };

        hideRetweets();

        // Twitter widget emitts no events on updates so we hook up ourselves to ol element to listen on it for additions of children
        var watcher = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
            // check whether new tweets arrived
            var hasNewTweets = mutations.some(function (mutation) {
                return mutation.addedNodes.length > 0;
            });
            if (hasNewTweets) {
                hideRetweets(); // rescan all tweets as it is easier
            }
        });
        watcher.observe(frameDoc.querySelector('ol.timeline-TweetList'), { childList: true });
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't handle new retweets after the widget has been set up (I'm assuming it shows new tweets), that's why I went with CSS injection in my answer.

Comment: you are right! I was thinking about it initially and somehow overlooked it in the end... We could additionally hook `MutationObserver` to `ol` in the frame and set listen to `childList` changes and then reexecute hiding, but I think getting out those additional borders this way rises way how it is hacky to the power of two ;) will give it a try simply to check how bad it can get ];>

Comment: Maybe there's a Twitter API hook for that but really, that's what CSS is good at, no need to overcomplicate :)

Comment: i couldn't find anything in the API documentation... personally i would go with CSS approach and forget about borders left behind there spoiling a little bit way how it looks

Answer (score 7):

It's quite easy. We will use for example [`caitp88`](https://twitter.com/caitp88) account for demo *<sup>you can follow her afterwards if you want tho)</sup>*

As you can see in her profile, the latest tweet is a Retweet
[image]

But we don't want retweets, right?

So we go to search form and type `from:caitp88 -RT`
[image]

Then we create an embed from this search
[image]
Widget configuration window opens, you just click on **create widget**

[image]

The widget will not contain any retweets
In action:
[image]

Don't forget to change `caitp88` to your own twitter handle

AND NOTE, THIS IS OFFICIAL, LEGAL SOLUTION

Comment: Sorry, just edited the question. I thought I had mentioned I tried and it doesn't work for me because tweets older than a week are not shown. Any way to get around that?

Comment: @Guido there is no other option indeed, _tweets older than a week are not shown_ maybe your account doesn't have new tweets, anyway try different accounts to be sure, `div.timeline-Tweet--isRetweet` cannot be used on iframe

Comment: My account has no new tweets. We tweet rarely, but we want our full timeline on our site. We can do that via a twitter list, but showing retweets. I guess I'm SOL? :)

Comment: try adding new tweets) maybe old tweets are not supported by new API, so you dont see them

Comment: This no longer works. https://twittercommunity.com/t/deprecating-widget-settings/102295

Answer (score 4):

I think "from:myaccount -RT" should work, as Medet Tleukabiluly has already mentioned. There are some things I want to add though:

1. -RT query will still include quoted retweets, since it's more like your own tweet than a RT.
2. If you want full control over the tweets, you can try [TwitterFetcher](http://jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/#sthash.nqQCL7LL.dpbs), which returns tweets as JSON data instead of embeded iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it using your CSS.

The Twitter timeline widget creates an IFrame into which I'm inserting a style tag containing your CSS. That has to happen after the widget has been loaded.

Of course, this is a brittle way to do it and might not work if Twitter changes the way it displays timelines.

```
// initialisation copied from Twitter API documentation
window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        t = window.twttr || {};
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

    t._e = [];
    t.ready = function(f) {
        t._e.push(f);
    };

    return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

twttr.ready(function(twttr) {
    twttr.events.bind("rendered", function(event) {
        var widgetIframe = event.target;

        var style = widgetIframe.contentDocument.createElement("style");
        style.innerHTML = "div.timeline-Tweet--isRetweet { display: none}";

        widgetIframe.contentDocument.head.appendChild(style);
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle with side-by-side-comparison of a feed using this technique: https://jsfiddle.net/cLc84Lrs/2/

Answer (score 1):

You have a few answers above on how to remove retweets but the problem on historical data is that twitter don't give out data more than a week or so in historical data. (related stackoverflow question: [Stackoverflow: Getting historical data from twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662151/getting-historical-data-from-twitter) )

The answer to this is paid services that gives historical data (with some rare free options). Example of these services are [Gnip](https://gnip.com/historical/) (with historical twitter api) or [Followthehashtag](http://followthehashtag.com/features/twitter-historical-data-recover/) (there you can do 1 search free per day that gives up to 500 tweets since 2006 but not sure about api support.)